# Saving PHP SESSION Cookie in Cordova iOS 6+

Tags: php, ios, cordova, wkwebview, cordova-ios

I'm upgrading a Cordova iOS 5.1.1 application (written still in jQuery) to iOS 6.1.1 platform as Apple rejects apps that still use UIWebView. I find the migration quite tough as my app is using loading JS files via Ajax, storing data in localStorage and storing PHP Session cookies and all of this data must be reachable now as well.

I have added cordova-plugin-migrate-localstorage plugin to migrate the localstorage data that UIWebView was using and it works fine. However, I cannot seem to find / implement a solution how to save cookies, especially PHP Session ID as it's mandatory that it doesn't change for each request, because PHP backend returns data depending on the SESSION data.

I've tried most of the plugins that were mentioned, for instance cordova-plugin-cookie-sync, cordova-plugin-cookie-inject etc. but none seem to work and store the Session ID.

Unfortunately I can only test the app in the simulator as none of my devices has i so I'm also wondering if there is a solution that doesn't demand having a physical device?

Am I doing a mistake and should stay on iOS 5.1.1 platform and just add wkWebView? I tried to play around a bit and just add the wkWebView Engine to it but it doesn't seem to know how to load local JS files.